# I've created a google apps login and want to migrate all of my accounts over to that

Tags: support, user-accounts

For some reason this is really difficult and not straight-forward to do.. I've successfully transferred some accounts (by associating 2 different non-google open id accounts to "get rid of" my non google apps login and then reassociating my new google apps account)

but on some sites I've accidentally created a NEW account and can't delete them... (for example my stackoverflow careers site)

there needs to be a way to delete an open id off of my account and to delete an account altogether...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "add / change openid" on your user profile to do this.

It is true that deleting an openid is not possible, so if you need that, email us.

Also, if you accidentally create a new account, you need that deleted or merged, so email us.

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick reply! i will need to compile a list of my accounts across multiple stackexchange sites and email you guys (i think i've tried and messed up on a lot of them). Is there a way (or will there be a way) to maintain to same open id accounts across all sites?